# stopping akka stream Source created from file on reaching file's end

Tags: scala, akka-stream, reactive-streams

I've created an akka-stream source by reading contents from a file.

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("reactive-process")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
implicit val ec: ExecutionContextExecutor = system.dispatcher

case class RequestCaseClass(data: String)

def httpPoolFlow(host: String, port: String) = Http().cachedHostConnectionPool[RequestCaseClass](host, port)(httpMat)

def makeFileSource(filePath: String) = FileIO.fromFile(new File(filePath))
  .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString(System.lineSeparator), 10000, allowTruncation = false))
  .map(_.utf8String)


def requestFramer = Flow.fromFunction((dataRow: String) =>
  (getCmsRequest(RequestCaseClass(dataRow)), RequestCaseClass(dataRow))
).filter(_._1.isSuccess).map(z => (z._1.get, z._2))

def responseHandler = Flow.fromFunction(
  (in: (Try[HttpResponse], RequestCaseClass)) => {
    in._1 match {
      case Success(r) => r.status.intValue() match {
        case 200 =>
          r.entity.dataBytes.runWith(Sink.ignore)
          logger.info(s"Success response for: ${in._2.id}")
          true
        case _ =>
          val b = Await.result(r.entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString.empty)(_ ++ _)(materializer)
            .map(bb => new String(bb.toArray))(materializer.executionContext), 60.seconds)
          logger.warn(s"Non-200 response for: ${in._2.id} r: $b")
          false
      }

      case Failure(t) =>
        logger.error(s"Failed completing request for: ${in._2.id} e: ${t.getMessage}")
        false
    }
  }
```

Now when using it in a runnable graph, I want the entire stream to stop on reaching End Of File being read using `makeFileSource(fp)`.

```
makeFileSource(fp)
  .via(requestFramer)
  .via(httpPoolFlow)
  .via(responseHandler)
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

The stream currently **doesn't stop** on reaching end of file.

Comment: More code to show what the rest of the pipeline is doing might help..

Comment: an akka-stream stops if the source stops emitting. I wanted viewers to focus only on the Source. If you feel w/o related code, the question gives incomplete context, I shall update the question. :)

Comment: Yes that was my point. Usually the more context there is, the better.

Comment: updated with some more code.